# add class to p:calendar, and p:selectOneMenu (reuired field) with jquery in jsf

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have problem with adding class to primefaces components with jquery. Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".required").each(function(){
            comp(this);
        });

        $(".required").change(function () {
            comp(this);
        });

        $(".required").blur(function ()  {
            comp(this);
        });

        $(".required").keyup(function ()  {
            comp(this);
        });

        $(".required").click(function ()  {
            comp(this);
        });
    });

    function comp(a) {
        if (!$(a).val()) {
            $(a).addClass('input_red');
            $(a).children('input').addClass( 'input_red');
        }
        else  {
            $(a).removeClass('input_red');
            $(a).children('input').removeClass( 'input_red');
        } 
    }
</script>
```

```html
<p:calendar pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" navigator="true"  id="datea" yearRange="2000" mode="popup" size="5" styleClass="required"   /> 
    <p:selectOneMenu converter="#{classificatorBean.bankConverter}" value="#{contractBean.sBank}" styleClass="required" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Birini saýla" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{contractBean.ucunjiBankList}" var="bn" itemLabel="#{bn.bankName}" itemValue="#{bn}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Could you also please provide the HTML rendered by your JSF.

Comment: I want set required fields border red when they are empty. I use for this jquery to bind events. In class "input_red" this parametrs [background:#fff2f1 !important; border:1px solid red !important; ]. It works only for inputfileds. But not set some primeface components;

Answer (score 1):

`p:calendar` is being eventually rendered (in HTML) as

```
 <span id="datea" class="required">
     <input id="datea_input" ....
```

so your selector should look like `$("span .required")`

My guess is that for `p:selectOneMenu` you can use this selector : `$("div .required")`
if won't work you'll have to "view source" (just like I did with p:calendar) and figure out the right selector...

Comment: Sorry but in my application not working . Also I need remove  input_red class  after date select.